# javascript/jquery: looking for image-fading script

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fading

i'm looking for a lightweight script (pure javascript preferred) - it should be for smoothly fading a sequence of images into each other (=image-carousel).
it should also be possible to run several instances (so it should be a prototype script), 
like for example:
- site banner: fading 3 images after each other
- main content: 3 galleries, each fading 3-5 images

any recommendations which script to use for that purpose?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the jQuery [CrossSlide plugin](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/) and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I've written a simple script which makes use of the jQuery .fadeOut() and .fadeIn() methods along with a few lines of html and css.  With the ids for the image elements numbered 1 to n the algorithm can easily iterate through the images and start again when it gets to the last image. It could be easily adapted to make the transitions occur automatically after a certain time delay instead of firing on a button click. Let me know if this helps. Here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #images{ overflow:auto; }
        .current{ display:inline; }
        .hidden{ display:none; }            
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    function doFade(current){

        var speed = 500;
        next = $("#"+(parseInt(current.attr("id")) + 1));
        if(next.length <= 0) next = $("#1");
        current.fadeOut(speed, 
            function fadeNextIn(){
                current.attr("class", "hidden");
                next.fadeIn(speed, 
                    function afterFadeNextIn(){
                        next.attr("class","current");
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }

    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#btnNext").click( 
                function(){ 
                    doFade($("#images .current"));
                }
            );
        }
    );

</script>

<div id="images">

    <img id="1" title="image 1" alt="image 1" src="1.jpg" class="current" />
    <img id="2" title="image 2" alt="image 2" src="2.jpg" class="hidden" />
    <img id="3" title="image 3" alt="image 3" src="3.jpg" class="hidden"/>
    <img id="4" title="image 4" alt="image 4" src="4.jpg" class="hidden"/>

</div>

<input id="btnNext" type="button" value="next" />
```